# Writing a common subject-observer implementation in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class that implements a beautiful subject-observer pattern thus. (This is Swift 3; Swift 2 would be no different in essence.)

```
protocol Delegate : class
{
    func method()
}

class Subject
{
    private typealias WeakDelegate = WeakReference< Delegate >
    private var nextAvailableDelegateId = 0
    private var delegates = [ Int : WeakDelegate ]()

    @discardableResult
    public func addDelegate( _ delegate: Delegate ) -> Int
    {
        let id = nextAvailableDelegateId
        nextAvailableDelegateId += 1
        delegates[ id ] = WeakDelegate( value: delegate )
        return id
    }

    public func removeDelegate( _ idForDelegate: Int )
    {
        delegates.removeValue( forKey: idForDelegate )
    }

    fileprivate func eachDelegate( fn: (Delegate) -> Void )
    {
        for (key, weakDelegate) in delegates
        {
            // Has this weak delegate reference become nil?
            //
            guard let delegate = weakDelegate.value else
            {
                // Yes. Remove it.
                delegates.removeValue( forKey: key )
                continue
            }

            fn( delegate )
        }
    }

    private func exampleNotifier()
    {
        eachDelegate{ $0.method() }
    }
}
```

(I'm taking the idiomatic Swift term "delegate" as roughly equivalent to the design pattern concept "observer".)

The `WeakReference` type above isn't strictly speaking part of this question, but in case you're curious:

```
public class WeakReference< T >
{
    public var value: T?
    {
        return abstractValue as? T
    }

    public init( value: T )
    {
        abstractValue = value as AnyObject
    }

    private weak var abstractValue: AnyObject?
}
```

Now I want to create another class analogous to `Subject` with another delegate protocol analogous to `Delegate`. How do I use the implementation I've already written for `Subject` in the new class?

One answer is to copy and paste the code. Not a good answer.

In C++ we could create a true mixin, a class that contains all the code and data necessary to implement the Subject, templated on a generic Delegate type, and inherit from it wherever we want to make some other class act as a Subject. Quite trivial.

Protocols, protocol extensions, and generics seem to have some of the machinery necessary for this kind of code reuse, but I can't work out how to accomplish it.

Help?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but can you not inherit from `Subject` for your new class?

Comment: @sdasdadas Imagine that I need a new pair of classes, `NewSubject` and `NewDelegate`. The question is: how do I inherit `Subject` such that `NewDelegate` becomes the new delegate type, such that, for example, `eachDelegate()` takes a function taking a `NewDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocol inheritance and generics to derive from some basic protocol.

Each new delegate will inherit from a parent class:

```
protocol Delegate: class {

    func method()
}

protocol DelegateA: Delegate { }

protocol DelegateB: Delegate { }
```

Your parent subject class can be implemented using a generic conforming to your parent protocol.

```
class Subject<T: Delegate> {

    private typealias WeakDelegate = WeakReference<T>
    private var nextAvailableDelegateId = 0
    private var delegates = [Int: WeakDelegate]()

    @discardableResult
    public func addDelegate(_ delegate: T) -> Int {
        let id = nextAvailableDelegateId
        nextAvailableDelegateId += 1
        delegates[id] = WeakDelegate( value: delegate )
        return id
    }

    public func removeDelegate(_ idForDelegate: Int) {
        delegates.removeValue(forKey: idForDelegate)
    }

    fileprivate func eachDelegate( fn: (T) -> Void ) {
        for (key, weakDelegate) in delegates {
            // Has this weak delegate reference become nil?
            guard let delegate = weakDelegate.value else {
                // Yes. Remove it.
                delegates.removeValue( forKey: key )
                continue
            }
            fn( delegate )
        }
    }

    private func exampleNotifier() {
        eachDelegate{ $0.method() }
    }
}
```

Each new subject can be instantiated as a generic conforming to your child delegates.

```
class SubjectA<T: DelegateA>: Subject<T> { }

class SubjectB<T: DelegateB>: Subject<T> { }
```

Comment: Well, I wish that worked. But you can't use a protocol to instantiate a generic in Swift. Consequently, you can't inherit a `SubjectA` such that it can operate on a new protocol type of `DelegateA`. You would have to use a concrete type (some implementation of protocol `DelegateA`) to instantiate the SubjectA class, and then you've defeated the purpose of having a subject class with an observer protocol. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/33503602/358475.

Comment: @OldPeculier I'm afraid I still don't understand. Something will have to be a concrete type when you do instantiate. I think maybe it's a bit too abstract for me to fully understand. Could you provide an example with `NewSubject` and `NewDelegate` implementations? I'll leave my answer up for a short while in case anyone can correct it.

Comment: @OldPeculier Ah, I understand now that I've had a bit more time with it. I thought extensions would get around it but it seems that the issues lies solely with the fact that you can't use a protocol to conform to the generic argument. Wish I could've helped more!